# How do i combine validation error objects in Symfony 4?

Tags: validation, symfony4

My api receives an json object posted from my React app. The object has two properties, one holding an array of objects and the other holds an id number. Because the first array cannot be validated by Symfony's form validation, I have created an custom restraint for it.

```php
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

$custom_constraint = new Assert\blah blah;
$errors = $validator->validate($data['datas'], $custom_constraint );

if (count($errors) > 0 ) {
    $errorsString = (string) $errors;
    return new JsonResponse(
        [
            'validation failed' => $errorsString                    
        ]);
}
```

This validation works by itself, but I also want to add the validation for the id number

```php
$errors = $validator->validate($data['id'], new Assert\Type('integer'));
```

Now I have two results in the `$errors` object, how do I combine them into one error object that output errors for any one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AssertCollection`. It's demonstrate here: [How to Validate Raw Values](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html)